# How to specify a different ip address in virtual box guest os

Tags: ip-address, virtualbox

I am using Windows 7 as the host. And xp as guest. 
I've already check out this site: http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=17232
But the info is not complete.
What do I need to set here, so that the guest would have another IP Address but can still connect to the internet.
Because what I'm trying to accomplish here is to be able to try Team Viewer or Cross loop. With the host os and guest os. Because I only have one computer.

[image: Virtual Box Settings]

Comment: Does your Windows 7 box have a public IP address or is it behind a NAT router?  I'm not familiar with Team Viewer or Cross loop, do you need to be able to access the guest OS from the external network?

Comment: nope, its just ordinary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't set the guest IP from Virtualbox, you just set it to bridged mode and then set it from inside the guest like you would on a physical machine.

Comment: how do I do it?:]

Comment: @Nrew - The same way you would on a regular computer. No trickery. Log into the guest OS, open network preferences and set whatever IP is appropriate for your network.

Comment: nope , the first one. The set to bridge mode, is it set to bridged mode by default.

Comment: @Nrew - ...it's selected right in the screenshot that you posted.